# js papa.parse csv file from url, prevent cache

Tags: javascript, papaparse

I am parsing a csv file that's on the server:

```
var readCSV = function(url){
    Papa.parse(url, {
        download: true,
        header: true,
        complete: function(results) {
            listen = results.data;
        }
    });
}
```

Unfortunately still reads an old file from cache even though I have already replaced it on the server. Is there some way to prevent it from using the cache?

Answer (score 10):

You could use a cachebuster to read your new file. So your URL should look like.

```
var readCSV = function(url){
    Papa.parse(url+"?_="+ (new Date).getTime(), {
        download: true,
        header: true,
        complete: function(results) {
            listen = results.data;
        }
    });
}
```